# Build Failed on Android Studio Google Codelabs 01.3 Text and Scrolling Views

Tags: java, android

I am working through the [Google Codelabs Android Fundamentals 01.3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-text-and-scrolling-views/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#2). I am catching errors during the build. I believe the problem has to do with resource id but after combing through the code and comparing it to the Codelabs solution code I am not finding the bug. I'm sure its something simple but I'm unable to find it. Any help would be great.

Activity_Main:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article_heading"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/article_title"
    android:textAppearance=
        "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
    android:layout_below="@id/article_heading"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/article_subtitle"
    android:textAppearance=
        "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_below="@id/article_subheading"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/article_text" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

edit:

build failed    25 s 998 ms
Run build   25 s 628 ms
null
Program type already present: androidx.viewpager.R
Program type already present: androidx.core.R
null
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process /Users/alanwayne/Documents/AlanWayneDesign/Android/ScrollingText/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/alanwayne/Documents/AlanWayneDesign/Android/ScrollingText/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: androidx.core.R 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process /Users/alanwayne/Documents/AlanWayneDesign/Android/ScrollingText/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/alanwayne/Documents/AlanWayneDesign/Android/ScrollingText/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: androidx.viewpager.R

Comment: welcome to SO, what is the error log you are catching?

Comment: thanks, Im glad to be here. I added the error log to the original post.